# Scala Processing a file in batches

Tags: scala

I have a flat file which contains several million lines like one below

```
59, 254, 2016-09-09T00:00, 1, 6, 3, 40, 18, 0
```

I want to process this file in batches of X rows at a time. So I wrote this code

```
def func(x: Int) = {
   for {
      batches <- Source.fromFile("./foo.txt").getLines().sliding(x, x)
   } yield batches.map("(" + _ + ")").mkString(",")
}
func(2).foreach(println)
```

This code produces exactly the output I want. the function walks through entire file taking 2 rows at a time batch them into 1 string.

```
(59, 828, 2016-09-09T00:00, 0, 8, 2, 52, 0, 0),(59, 774, 2016-09-09T00:00, 0, 10, 2, 51, 0, 0)
```

But when I see scala pros write code everything happens inside the for comprehension and you just return the last thing from your comprehension.

So in order to be a scala pro I change my code

```
for {
   batches <- Source.fromFile("./foo.txt").getLines().sliding(2, 2)
   line <- batches.map("(" + _ + ")").mkString(",")
} yield line
```

This produces 1 character per line and not the output I expected. Why did the code behavior totally change? At least on reading they look the same to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `line <- batches.map("(" + _ + ")").mkString(",")`, the right-hand side produces a `String` (the result of `mkString`), and the loop iterates over this string.  When you iterate over a string, the individual items are characters, so in your case `line` is going to be a character.  What you actually want is not to iterate over that string, but to assign it to the variable name `line`, which you can do by replacing the `<-` with `=`: `line = batches.map("(" + _ + ")").mkString(",")`.

By the way, `sliding(2,2)` can be more clearly written as `grouped(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

@dhg has given the explaination, here's my suggestion on how this could be done in another way

```
for {
   batches <- Source.fromFile("./foo.txt").getLines().sliding(2, 2)
   batch <- batches.map("(" + _ + ")")
} yield batch.mkString(",")
```

so `batch` would be a traversable consist of 2 lines

---